# opengl version 1.2 api?

Tags: c++, opengl

Where can I find the documentations for OpenGL version prior to 2.0?
On the website: opengl.org, they are only listing the new api's.

My situation is: I've got this really only laptop that I'm developing on, and realized that some of opengl's methods were not available for this computer.

So far, I've worked around some of the problem by testing against a condition of the users version. Those with newer than 2.0(inclusive) would be using the newer code, whereas those with versions prior to 2.0 would be using the ARB extended methods.

Example:

```
if(m_glVersion>2){//Integer value of your opengl version
    glGenBuffers(NUM_BUFFERS, m_vertexArrayBuffers);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertexArrayBuffers[POSITION_VB]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(model.positions[0]) * model.positions.size(), &model.positions[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertexArrayBuffers[TEXCOORD_VB]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(model.texCoords[0]) * model.texCoords.size(), &model.texCoords[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertexArrayBuffers[NORMAL_VB]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(model.normals[0]) * model.normals.size(), &model.normals[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertexArrayBuffers[INDEX_VB]);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(model.indices[0]) * model.indices.size(), &model.indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}else{
    glGenBuffersARB(NUM_BUFFERS, m_vertexArrayBuffers);
    glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertexArrayBuffers[POSITION_VB]);
    glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(model.positions[0]) * model.positions.size(), &model.positions[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArrayARB(0);
    glVertexAttribPointerARB(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertexArrayBuffers[TEXCOORD_VB]);
    glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(model.texCoords[0]) * model.texCoords.size(), &model.texCoords[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArrayARB(1);
    glVertexAttribPointerARB(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertexArrayBuffers[NORMAL_VB]);
    glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(model.normals[0]) * model.normals.size(), &model.normals[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArrayARB(2);
    glVertexAttribPointerARB(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glBindBufferARB(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertexArrayBuffers[INDEX_VB]);
    glBufferDataARB(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(model.indices[0]) * model.indices.size(), &model.indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}
```

http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vbo.html provided some good source on mesh creating and deleting however, there is none available about shaders.

Getting an error on: glCreateProgram, my current assumption is that it doesn't support version below 2.0. https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glCreateProgram.xhtml

I could not find an ARB version of this method. Is there one? Work-around?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at https://www.opengl.org/registry/ it's right below OpenGL-2

OpenGL-1.2 specification: https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec121_bookmarked.pdf

There never was a HTML online reference, however most Linux distributions have a Mesa documentation package that contains manpages for all the OpenGL functions; OpenGL-2.x is a true superset of OpenGL-1.x without any depreciations.

> mesh creating and deleting however, there is none available about shaders.

GLSL shader support was introduced only with OpenGL-2; however they are usually available as an extension, but if your target system does not support OpenGL-2 it is very unlikely that is has programmable hardware at all; probably register combiners, but that's about it.

Comment: I am unable to load that pdf doc of 1.2 specs; I saw it while searching but it was and still is still not access-able to me. The openGL 1.4 doc is though =D is there a significant difference between 1.2 and 1.4? checking. https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec14.pdf

Comment: @doingit: If I click that link I gave you it will download just fine. Maybe your browser is ill configured. Try right-click→Save As use a different browser or try downloading with a dedicated download tool (wget or similar).

Comment: Thanks for your help, as you've said, there is very little support for shaders in legacy opengl; I've simply neglected adding shaders to a mesh if the device has legacy opengl. And yes, the pdf would not open on chrome::lubuntu14.04LTS, but it does work with windows7::chrome. Not sure what's going on, but thanks for the info.